# How much memory does one ViewController take?

Tags: ios, memory, uiviewcontroller

I would like to know how much memory does a single `ViewController` take , because when I'm developing some apps I'm still not sure if it is better to create more `ViewControllers` , or if I should create less `ViewControllers` and change things in code , instead of `UserInterface`.

Example of what I mean: Let's say that I have two types of data and I want to see them on presented `ViewController`, but these two types are almost the same. So should I have only one `ViewController` and change things in code or I can just create `ViewController` for every type?

I know that it depends on how much code and how much things are in the UI but let's say that it is a few lines of code and just a very basic `ViewController`

I have looked into The Role of View Controllers 
by Apple but I could not find the answer.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH2-SW1

I know that it's a bit weird , but I'm really curious.
Thanks.

Comment: This question is a big vague and difficult to answer in the abstract. If you can give a practical example of the actual two types you're thinking about, we can probably offer better counsel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An uninstantiated view controller doesn't use any memory. It's takes a trivial amount of disk space as part of the app, but no memory at runtime until it is created and displayed.

You are currently guilty of premature optimization. Write your code properly so it is easy to write, easy to maintain, and easy to debug. Don't worry about things like memory usage and performance until you have a problem that needs to be addressed.

If you have two different screens with two different types of data, then create two different view controllers.

Once it is working, then run it through Instruments and confirm you have no leaks or reference cycles wasting memory.

Answer (score 1):

The size of extra view controller classes in your code is negligible, so unless you're talking about some extreme number of them, I wouldn't worry about that. The governing principle here is more likely to be [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). If you've got a bunch of objects that differ in very small ways (e.g. the names on labels, etc.), then perhaps you can create a common protocol to which all of these objects conform, and then you can write a view controller designed for that protocol, rather than any particular object. But if you find yourself adding a bunch of unwieldy `if` statements and programmatically adding controls, simply to avoid having multiple scenes in your storyboard, then you may have gone too far.